# How the big website('s company) name their HTML classes

Tags: html

I wonder how big websites like google, instagram, facebook....recoganize their class names. They looks so random in the first sights but have some kinds of trends in them; for example: all the profile photos have class of `"_6q-tv"`;Is there a rule behinds those names?; Another thing I saw is, in extends functions such as drop down menus tends to have even more weird classes, they have classes with space for example, `"NXc7H jLuN9  X6gVd"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They use meaningful class names in the source code, but then use a preprocessor/compiler/bundler (such as webpack) to convert the class names to short ones in order to make things smaller.

Of course those few bytes are not much, but if you get billions or trillions of requests every month, it starts summing up.

Comment: can you also explain why some of those classes have spaces? thanks

Comment: because there are multiple classes on one element